# get things out of bag in pig

Tags: hadoop, group-by, apache-pig, bag

### In the pig example:

```
A = LOAD 'student.txt' AS (name:chararray, term:chararray, gpa:float);

DUMP A;
(John,fl,3.9F)
(John,wt,3.7F)
(John,sp,4.0F)
(John,sm,3.8F)
(Mary,fl,3.8F)
(Mary,wt,3.9F)
(Mary,sp,4.0F)
(Mary,sm,4.0F)

B = GROUP A BY name;

DUMP B;
(John,{(John,fl,3.9F),(John,wt,3.7F),(John,sp,4.0F),(John,sm,3.8F)})
(Mary,{(Mary,fl,3.8F),(Mary,wt,3.9F),(Mary,sp,4.0F),(Mary,sm,4.0F)})

C = FOREACH B GENERATE A.name, AVG(A.gpa);

DUMP C;
({(John),(John),(John),(John)},3.850000023841858)
({(Mary),(Mary),(Mary),(Mary)},3.925000011920929)
```

---

The last output A.name is a bag. How can I get things out of bag:

```
(John, 3.850000023841858)
(Mary, 3.925000011920929)
```

Answer (score 4):

`GROUP` creats a magical item called `group`, which is what you grouped on. This is made for exactly this purpose.

```
B = GROUP A BY name;

C = FOREACH B GENERATE group AS name, AVG(A.gpa);
```

Check out `DESCRIBE B;`, you'll see that `group` is in there. It is a single value that represents what was in the `BY ...` part of the `GROUP`.